# chopped up video/display picture

Tags: nvidia, graphics, video

I have a laptop with a dedicated nvidia GTX 960M and an intel chip. I am currently using the 352.79 driver as [recommended](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa). But I am experience some unpleasant graphic glitches:

[image]

[image]

Those glitches do not only occur when watching videos (in this case netflix using the current chrome) but also when scrolling a webpage in the browser or using the command line. Running the glxgears returns an average of 1684fps.

*If there is a more appropriate description of the phenomenon please feel free to edit the title - I was unable to come up with anything more precise.*

Comment: Try the latest drivers. The recommendation doesn't mean much  in case you have troubles.

Comment: It looks like you're using an external display: are you sure your cable/connector is not defect? this can cause errors in data transmission in digital video cables.

Comment: @Reboot as the main display experiences the same problem, and the problem does not occur on my windows OS. I highly doubt that this is the problem.

Comment: This is called "video tearing".  There are a lot of questions about this, even a dedicated tag: http://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/tearing Try reading there further as the problems and the solutions vary for each graphics card and driver version.

Comment: I've noticed that you mentioned also an Intel card. In that case the applications are actually rendered through that one. I know how to fix tearing on intel with compton, but only on Xubuntu. For Ubuntu you need to find another solution. Maybe this: https://blog.lxgr.net/posts/2015/04/27/chrome-linux-vsync/

Comment: @o9000 I also have a dedicated Nvidia card - thus it would be easier to forcibly switch the rendering GPU (if it is possible).